# How does one change Terminal.app profile for all open tabs using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, themes

Would love to know if there is a way to switch all my current Terminal.app tabs to a *different profile* on the fly.

The use-case being to change Terminal profile from a dark to a light theme, and vice versa, depending on a user's current mood/preference. This can be achieved manually by right clicking on a Tab header and choosing "Inspect tab", and then changing the theme for each tab.

The other option is to close down all the open tabs and reopen them with a new theme, again suboptimal IMHO.

Hope someone has a better way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an AppleScript like this one, and call it something like TerminalNightMode:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set current settings of tabs of windows to settings set "Pro"
end tell
```

You can replace the "Pro" setting with the setting name of your choice. When you run this AppleScript, it will change the settings for all the tabs in all windows. I recommend putting this script on the dock for easy access. Likewise, you can make another script for day mode.